# Can i group values in a column and sum their totals in emeditor?

Tags: emeditor

Please how do i group a column and sum up their corresponding values in Emeditor? Similar to "Group by" in Power Query or PowerBi. For Example:

File

```
NAME    COST
John    5
Mike    3
Dan     5
John    2
Dan     8
John    5
```

Expected Outcome

```
NAME    COST
John    12
Mike    3
Dan     13
```

In this case i get the total cost of each value under "Name Column" in the file

Comment: Are these two columns separated by a tab or spaces?

Comment: The two columns are separated by a Comma (CSV)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming two columns are separated by a tab, you can use EmEditor to sort by the first column, combine lines, and then use a regular expression with JavaScript to replace the second column. If you want to do it fast, you can skip to **Using a Macro** section.

1. Open your file.
2. Click the **Tab** button on the **CSV/Sort** toolbar to swtich to the Tab-separated CSV mode.

[image: EmEditor - CSV/Sort toolbar]

3. Click the **Heading** button on the **CSV/Sort** toolbar, and then select **Heading 1**.
4. Select the first column, and the click the **Sort A to Z** button on the **CSV/Sort** toolbar to sort the first column.
5. Right-Click on the **Column 1** of the Headings (or select the **CSV** sub menu on the **Edit** menu), then select **Combine Lines**.
6. Ensure the `1: COST` check box in the **Columns to inspect duplicates** is set, and `2: NAME` check box in the **Columns to combine** is set. Enter `+` to the **String to Insert** text box.  Click **OK**.

[image: EmEditor - Combine Lines]

7. Select the second column, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to bring up the **Replace** dialog box, enter `[\d\+]+\d` to the **Find** text box, and `\J eval("\0");` to the **Replace with** text box, set the **In the Selection Only** and **Regular Expressions** options, and click **Replace All**.

[image: EmEditor - Replace]

**Using a Macro**

If you want to use a macro, you can run the following macro after opening your file.

```
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22529);  // TSV
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(3894);   // Heading 1
document.selection.StartOfDocument(false);
document.Sort("1>A+",eeSortBinaryComparison,"");
document.CombineLines("1","2","+","",0,"");
document.selection.SetActivePoint( eePosCellLogical, 2, 1 );
editor.ExecuteCommandByID(4461);   // Select Column
document.selection.Replace("[\\d\\+]+\\d","\\J eval(\"\\0\");",eeFindReplaceSelOnly | eeReplaceAll | eeFindReplaceRegExp,0);
document.selection.Collapse();
```

To run this, save this code as, for instance, `GroupCol.jsee`, and then select this file from **Select...** in the **Macros** menu. Finally, open your file to convert, and select **Run GroupCol.jsee** in the **Macros** menu while the file you want to convert is active.

Comment: Thank you so much! The two columns are separated by a Comma. I tried your solution and it actually worked. However, after giving me the results, the emeditor keeps crashing when i use the Macro you provided.

Comment: If it's a comma-separated file, the first line of the macro should be `editor.ExecuteCommandByID(22528);`.  Please make sure you are using the newest version of EmEditor, and if it still crashes, please email the crash report file to tech @ emurasoft.com with detailed procedure to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Many thanks! It still crashes on the latest version so i have sent the crash report via email to tech@emurasoft.com as requested

Comment: Please make sure your CSV syntax is valid. Are there any `Inconsistent number of columns detected` errors in your CSV? If so, you can use the `Make Number of Columns Same` command, or manually correct your CSV file. I also found an error in the `Replace` method of my macro.  I already updated my answer (added a semicolon `;` to the replace expression, and added extra backslashes  to the find expression). Please update your macro accordingly.

Comment: The CSV Syntax is valid and there are no inconsistent number of columns. Tried the edited macro & It always crashes half way through the process. Is there anyway to send you the file?

Comment: I've emailed you an instruction.

Comment: I received your sample file, and your sample included some empty cells/invalid characters. I've updated my answer to support your case.